# Interactive Broker API returns wrong volume value

Tags: c#, interactive-brokers

Using IB Api C#. Trying to request historical data but my result for volume is different from IB official website volume for the product. Am I doing it wrong or it has something to do with a real-time subscription? I am not subscribed yet. Here is my request:

```
private static void getHistoricalData(EClientSocket client, string symbol, int tickerId)
        {
            Contract contract = new();

            contract.Symbol = symbol;
            contract.SecType = "STK";
            contract.Exchange = "SMART";
            contract.Currency = "USD";

            string queryTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss");

            client.reqHistoricalData(tickerId, contract, queryTime, "1 D", "1 day", "TRADES", 1, 1, false, null);

            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
```

As I understand that should return the previous day's total traded volume?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I have the same issue, do you found how to solve it?

Comment: This is intended: "IB's historical data feed is filtered for some types of trades which generally occur away from the NBBO such as combos, block trades, and derivatives. For that reason the historical data volume will be lower than an unfiltered historical data feed." - https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/historical_bars.html